# Is it secure to build android app that works with PHP API on browser?

Tags: java, php, android

I'm learning to build android apps using java & android studio.
For my app i need internet connection and a server side database, I'm already php developer so i tought to build a PHP web API and by json, send and recieve data from specific URL.

For example, any user that will register inside my app, i can send his data to:

(via POST or GET method.)

```
example.com/api/user_register.php
```

Is it secure? How can i get data and send to an existing domain in java?
I'm looking for something similliar to file_get_content() or CURL in PHP.

Also i need to build something like push notifications..

Comment: "How can i get data and send to an existing domain in java? I'm looking for something similliar to file_get_content() or CURL in PHP". What do you mean by that ?

Comment: How to get content of specific url in java, so i can get data from the database.

Im looking for something like file_get_contents() (in php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating an web API to access a MySQL Database for Android is expected as there is no direct connection to the database possible on Android.

I've done something similar with one of my own apps. How secure it is depends on how you make it and where your PHP API is. I.e. is the data being sent to/from HTTP or HTTPS. In my own app, I encrypt the post data on the device, post it to my PHP API which decrypts and processes the request.

It then builds a response and json_encodes it, which is then encrypted and sent back to the device, where the device decrypts it and processes the JSON result. All of this is also done over HTTPS so hopefully, its fairly secure.

Comment: Thanks! so how can i send a request to a web server in java?

Comment: Hopefully https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_php_mysql.htm can point you in the right direction. Don't forget though you will need to do the posting to the web server in an asynctask. Don't do it in the GUI thread or you will throw an exception

Comment: Thanks!

"Don't do it in the GUI thread or you will throw an exception" What does that mean?

Comment: Unless you create a new thread, any action you do is on the main thread - this controls the GUI (Graphical User Interface). If you do long operations on this thread - such as network operations you will receive an exception NetworkOnMainThreadException. Other tasks that you do that are slow which are done on the main thread will result in an ANR (Application Not Responding) message